# How to read and continue from a file containing list of numbers

Tags: python

What I'm trying to reach is:

I have an script which sends SMS to clients who have agreed to receive from my number, and all numbers are in a `txt` file. The script is reading from this file line by line and sends SMS to each number in each iteration.

The issue is if I stop script and re-run it, it will send again from first number.

I want to generate another file containing to which numbers it's been sent, and checks the last number and continue from that.

I know the first part to write and append, but I don't know the second part.

This is an example of my code:

```
file = open('pywhatkit_dbs.txt', 'r')
for number in file:
    send_sms()
    if send_sms():
        file.write('sent_numbers.txt', 'a')
```

Comment: What do you want to do if sending the SMS is unsuccessful?

Comment: @oda my cell operator tries for the next 24 hour and I can see in the panel if any SMS is not delivered

Comment: the `if send_sms()` says, "if sending the message was successful"? Will you be adding new numbers to your input file as well? So you would want to start from the last number you successfully sent an SMS from?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer is what you were looking for or not! I had to make a few guesses about your exact requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the answers soon (your and others).

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure that the python script will continue running until all messages have been sent and the script won't run again afterwards, then @shah sawood's answer will do fine. If that's not the case, you'll have to store all the numbers that you've sent an sms to in a file, I think that's what you were looking for.

You could try something like this:

```
with open("numbers.txt", 'r') as numbers_file, open("sent_numbers.txt", 'a') as sent_numbers_file:
for number in numbers_file:
    send_sms(number)
    sent_numbers_file.write(number)
```

Then you'll just have to implement some logic that checks whether a number is already in the sent_numbers.txt before actually sending the sms.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("in.txt") as f, open("out.txt", "a+") as g:
    g.seek(0)          # set position to beginning of file

    sent = ""          # useful if out.txt empty
    # find last number we successfully sent sms to
    for sent in g:
        pass
    last_number = sent # last number we successfully sent sms to (plus newline)

    if last_number:    # if out.txt not empty
        # iterate through f until we find last successful number
        for number in f:
            if last_number == number:
                break

    # start sending messages, starting from first number after last successful
    # one or from the beginning if no numbers in out.txt
    for number in f:
        print("Sending SMS")
        if True: # sending SMS successful
            g.write(number)
        else:    # sending SMS unsuccesful
            print("sending SMS unsuccessful.")
            break
```

`in.txt` is a file containing phone numbers, each one on a different line.
`out.txt` records all the numbers for which an SMS was successful, each one on a different line. We open the former for reading and the latter for reading and writing (append if file exists). The `"a+"` means open the file for reading and writing (append if file exists).

We set the position of `"out.txt"` to the beginning of the file and we iterate line by line through this file to find the last number sent and record this in `last_number`. If `"out.txt"` is empty, `last_number` will refer to the empty string `""`.

- If `last_number` is not the empty string, we iterate line-by-line through `"in.txt"` until we find the last successful number and then start sending sms messages starting from the first number after the last successful one.
- If `last_number` is the empty string (i.e. we have not yet had any successful SMSs), we start from the beginning of `"in.txt"` and send messages to each number.

In either case, every time we successfully send an SMS, we append the number to `"out.txt"`. If an SMS is unsuccessful, we stop.

Note if your input file is very large, you should consider storing the numbers in a binary file (both for `"in.txt"` and `"out.txt"`), in which case we can avoid having to loop through `"out.txt"` to get to the last line (we can use `seek` to get there efficiently). This looping method is still better then using something like `readlines()` in the event of a large file as it does not read the entire file into memory.

Also note, another more space-efficient strategy might be to only use one file, `"in.txt"`, with the first line containing a number containing the line number of the last successful number. However, in your question, you state that you wish to generate another file containing those numbers that an SMS has been sent to.

This is **one** strategy. I **made a few assumptions** as I do not know your exact requirements. For example, it would help me if I knew exactly what `sent_sms()` returns and what you want to do in the event that sending an SMS is unsuccessful. For example, if the SMS is unsuccessful at some number, when we start the script again, we can start sending SMSs from the number that follows that unsuccessful number. To implement this in the code above, regardless whether the SMS is successful or not (see the last `if` in the code), write the number to `"out.txt"`. The `"out.txt"` file in this case would represent **all attempted numbers** rather than **all successful numbers**. Then if an SMS is unsuccessful and the program stops, then the next time you run the program again, it starts at the number following the unsuccessful one. As it is currently implemented, with `"out.txt"` representing all successful numbers, if the program stops due to an unsuccessful message and you run the program again, it may stop again at that unsuccessful number.

Regardless, I hope this offers a decent base template from which you can modify to meet your exact requirements.

**Test**

---

Suppose `"in.txt"` is

```
0999999999
0888888888
```

Running the above code, the following lines are printed out

```
Sending SMS
Sending SMS
```

and `"out.txt"` becomes

```
0999999999
0888888888
```

Suppose `"in.txt"` has had a number appended to it so that it is

```
0999999999
0888888888
0777777777
```

Running the code again the following is printed out

```
Sending SMS
```

and `"out.txt"` is now

```
0999999999
0888888888
0777777777
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this might help you:

```
# declare a global list for keeping track of marked numbers
done = []
# open the file for reading
with open("filename.txt") as file:
    # loop through file
    for number in file:
        # check whether he's sent msg or not
        if number not done:
            send_sms()
            done.append(number)
```